Resource Group for Azure Functions
I tried to create a new Azure Functions app in an existing resource group that has my ASP.NET Core API app and received the following error:

LinuxDynamicWorkersNotAllowedInResourceGroup occurs when you attempt
to create a Linux Consumption function app in a resource group that
has previously contained another function app or web app that is
incompatible with the new app.

I've always used resource groups for keeping my production and staging environment resources grouped together.
Do I need to create a new resource group for my Azure Functions app? If so, can you tell me why?
BTW, both apps are .NET 8 apps that I want to run on Linux. The API app is an ASP.NET Core app using Azure App Service on Linux and runs fine. I was just trying to add a new Azure Functions app and use the existing resource group. Thanks.

Can you check the app service plan in which you are trying to create this new function app? May be the error is coming from there?

It appears it's due to not having the necessary resources in my existing resource group.

Looks like the answer is in the following link. The issue seems to be not having the necessary resources in the existing resource group. Switching to Windows hosting for my Azure Functions app or placing it in a new resource group works because that maps the plan for my Azure Functions app to a different pool of resources.
Here's the explanation why this error occurs:
https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/wiki/Creating-Function-Apps-in-an-existing-Resource-Group/736ab9f541b480a7f3a4c791b5af9f80300f3c46

Thanks for posting the answer. Every day you learn something new about Azure. I always thought that resource groups is just a "logical" container to group similar resources together.

That's precisely what I thought too!
